# XPath Xpression for XML-RPC

Tags: xpath, xml-rpc

I have following XMLRPC response

```
<value><struct>
        <member><name>dedicatedAccountID</name><value><i4>1</i4></value></member>
        <member><name>dedicatedAccountValue1</name><value><string>0</string></value></member>
        <member><name>expiryDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>99991231T00:00:00+1200</dateTime.iso8601></value></member>
    </struct></value>
    <value><struct>
        <member><name>dedicatedAccountID</name><value><i4>2</i4></value></member>
        <member><name>dedicatedAccountValue1</name><value><string>15635</string></value></member>
        <member><name>expiryDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>99991231T00:00:00+1200</dateTime.iso8601></value></member>
    </struct></value>
    <value><struct>
        <member><name>dedicatedAccountID</name><value><i4>3</i4></value></member>
        <member><name>dedicatedAccountValue1</name><value><string>0</string></value></member>
        <member><name>expiryDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>99991231T00:00:00+1200</dateTime.iso8601></value></member>
    </struct></value>
```

I want to get value of dedicatedAccountValue1 where member name is dedicatedAccountID its value is 1.

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Struct[member/name='dedicatedAccountID' and 
member/value/i4='1']/member[name='dedicatedAccountValue1']/value
```

Try this. Not tested

Answer (score 2):

`//value/struct[member[name = 'dedicatedAccountID' and value/* = '1']]/member[name = 'dedicatedAccountValue1']/value/*`